# Convert VBNet LiNQ to C#

Tags: c#, linq

how do i convert this into C# code?

```
Dim newArray() as String = From sRow In iDatatable.Rows.Cast(Of DataRow)() Where sRow("iType").ToString = "ST" Select CStr(sRow("iResult"))).ToArray()
```

i have tried this sites but none of them worked.

```
http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/
http://www.carlosag.net/Tools/CodeTranslator/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this would be equivelent:

```
string[] newArray = iDatatable.Rows.Cast<DataRow>()
         .Where(sRow => sRow["iType"].ToString() == "ST")
         .Select(sRow => sRow["iResult"].ToString())
         .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

Exactly the same, with minor differences.

```
string[] newArray = (from sRow in iDatatable.Rows.Cast<DataRow>() where sRow["iType"].ToString() == "ST" select (string)sRow["iResult"]).ToArray();
```

Comment: I'm a VB guy and slowly migrating to C#. When i use your code, an error occured saying, `Error 1 'System.Data.DataRowCollection' does not contain a definition for 'Cast' and the best extension method overload 'System.Data.EnumerableRowCollectionExtensions.Cast<TResult>(System.Data.Enumera‌​bleRowCollection)' has some invalid arguments`

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have this before the namespace.

```
using System.Linq;
```

then use

```
string[] newArray = iDatatable.Rows.Cast<DataRow>()
                .Where(sRow => sRow["iType"].ToString() == "ST")
                .Select(sRow => sRow["iResult"].ToString())
                .ToArray();
```